# Get Result of Stored Procedure Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, stored-procedures, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.4 and MySql 5.7, PHP 5.6.
I am trying to call a stored procedure (that does a SELECT query, joining multiple tables), and to get the result returned to my PHP.

Here are the things I've unsuccessfully tried:

**PHP 1:**

```
$result =  DB::select('CALL rentalsAvailables_get(?, ?, ?, ?)',
                array(
                    'p0' => Carbon::now(),
                    'p1' => Carbon::now()->addDays(7),
                    'p2' => 100,
                    'p3' => 2
                )
    );
return var_dump($result);
```

**Result 1:**

```
{
   "error": {
        "message": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031  (SQL: CALL rentalsAvailables_get(2017-03-11 16:00:42, 2017-03-18 16:00:42, 100, 2))",
        "code": "HY000",
        "status_code": 500
   }
}
```

**PHP 2:**

```
$result =  DB::select('CALL rentalsAvailables_get(:p0, :p1, :p2, :p3)',
                array(
                    'p0' => Carbon::now(),
                    'p1' => Carbon::now()->addDays(7),
                    'p2' => 100,
                    'p3' => 2
                )
    );
return var_dump($result);
```

**Result 2:**

```
array(0) {
}
```

** Stored Procedure: **

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `rentalsAvailables_get`(IN `startDate` DATETIME, IN `endDate` DATETIME, IN `maxPrice` INT(11) ZEROFILL, IN `capacity` INT(2))
    NO SQL
SELECT a.rentalId, a.rentalName, a.rentalBathroom, a.rentalBedroom, a.rentalCapacity, a.rentalCover, a.rentalLat, a.rentalLong, a.rentalLocation, a.rentalStatus, a.rentalSummary, a.rentalText, a.rentalOwnerId,
b.rentalTypeId, b.rentalTypeName,
c.id as 'userId', c.name,
d.rentalPriceId, d.rentalPrice

FROM rentals as a
INNER JOIN rentalTypes as b
ON a.rentalTypeId = b.rentalTypeId
INNER JOIN users as c
ON a.rentalOwnerId = c.id
INNER JOIN rentalprice as d
ON a.rentalId = d.rentalId

WHERE a.rentalCapacity > @p3
AND a.rentalStatus = true
AND d.rentalPrice < @p2
AND d.rentalPriceStartDate <= @p0
AND d.rentalPriceEndDate >= @p1
AND a.rentalId NOT IN (
        SELECT eSub.rentalId FROM unavailabilities as eSub WHERE eSub.unavailabilityStartDate >= @p0 AND eSub.unavailabilityEndDate <= @p1
    )
AND a.rentalId NOT IN (
        SELECT fSub.rentalId FROM rent as fSub WHERE fSub.rentStartDate >= @p0 AND fSub.rentEndDate <= @p1
    )$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Note:**

I have of course checked and i am getting results from my query when calling it like that:

```
SET @p0='2017-03-11 04:26:09.000000';
SET @p1='2017-03-17 04:26:09.000000';
SET @p2='1000';
SET @p3='2';
CALL `rentalsAvailables_get`(@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3);
```

Did anyone already got this issue?
Thanks for reading

Comment: Are you SURE you need procedure?

Comment: I could build the query with Laravel, but i would love to keep the complex queries inside my DB

Comment: The goal is to avoid complex query entirely.

Comment: Don't get me wrong i'm not talking about an insane query, just joining 3 tables and doing some filtering

Comment: Why not just leverage Eloquent, then?

Comment: I did it that way on the meanwhile @MarcoAurélioDeleu, but still would like to find the answer to my question, as I didn't found anything in the doc or searching on google

Comment: No problem with that. I was curious myself. But you just made your code a lot more easy to maintain in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass `CALL your_procedure` via `DB::raw` to `DB::SELECT`.

So this will work and it returns result set:

```
$p0 = Carbon::now();
$p1 = Carbon::now()->addDays(7);
$p2 = 100;
$p3 = 2;
DB::select(DB::raw("CALL rentalsAvailables_get($p0, $p1, $p2, $p3)"));
```

Also you can convert the result set to **Eloquent model** using `hydrate` method.

```
Foo::hydrate($result_from_db_select);
```

Hope this help you after 6 months :))

Answer (score 0):

You see this two values

```
2017-03-11 16:00:42, 2017-03-18 16:00:42//they are not escaped that's your problem
```

Solution -

```
$result =  \DB::statement('CALL rentalsAvailables_get(\'' . Carbon::now() . '\', \'' . Carbon::now()->addDays(7) . '\', 100, 2)')->fetchAll();
```

Comment: With this at least i'm not getting any error :)
But now i'm getting "bool(true)" as response

Comment: @ThibaudLacan without seeing your stored procedure I can't say anything

Comment: I've tried it and getting an error: "Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean"
I also have updated my question with my stored procedure.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ThibaudLacan you have to post your stored procedure then

Comment: @ARIF MAHMUD RANA Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838922/how-can-i-convert-many-statement-mysql-to-laravel-eloquent

Answer (score 0):

```
$result =  DB::select('CALL rentalsAvailables_get(?, ?, ?, ?)',
            array(
                'p0' => Carbon::now(),
                'p1' => Carbon::now()->addDays(7),
                'p2' => 100,
                'p3' => 2
            )
);
```

above is bind param by index 
=> only need like below is enough

```
$result =  DB::select('CALL rentalsAvailables_get(?, ?, ?, ?)',
            array(
                Carbon::now(),
                Carbon::now()->addDays(7),
                100,
                2
            )
);
```

Pls read more about PHP PDO