# How to get inserted id using insert stored procedure in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, database, laravel, stored-procedures, laravel-5.3

My stored procedure : setUsers

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblusers (email,password) values (email,password);
    SET id =  LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

My laravel code:

```
 DB::insert('call tblusers (?,?,@id)',array($req->email,Hash::make(($req->password))))
```

Here I have tried with lastInsertId(); and insertGetId(); but it always returns a boolean.

Comment: Will https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760414/mysql-stored-procedure-return-value help? Otherwise, please add the complete definition of your stored procedure

Comment: Actually when I use my mentioned stored procedure in phpmyadmin and insert data using it, it returns an inserted id as 'id' column. But I want to handle it via laravel code mean when I use this code how I can save last inserted id in variable?

Comment: Can you share the **exact** definition of your stored procedure?

Comment: Probably, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737433/get-result-of-stored-procedure-laravel will help?

Comment: I have just written BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblusers (email,password) values (email,password);
    SET id =  LAST_INSERT_ID();
END and in laravel code I have just written $myid =  DB::insert('call tblusers (?,?,@id)',array($req->email,Hash::make(($req->password))))
but here I am getting boolean in $myid instead of inserted id

Comment: And your definition has no parts defining the name and input variables?

Comment: it has id, email and password in table

Comment: Have you tried something else than `DB::insert`? You are not actually inserting anything, but calling that stored procedure. And it does nothing more than returning the ID? That's something each ORM can handle on its own, without using SP

Comment: Yes I have tried with DB::insert, DB::statements and DB::raw also. It inserts with the help of stored procedure call but it should return and id but it always returns bool(true)

Comment: And why do you need to use a stored procedure after all?

Comment: Actually its my project's requirement to use stored procedure otherwise insertGetId(); works find with laravel code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737433/get-result-of-stored-procedure-laravel link is helpful but its for select not an insert.

Comment: If I run stored procedure in phpmyadmin, it works perfectly and returns inserted id. But I do not know how to store this inserted id with laravel code? Could anyone help please?